# Can I send the same data using POST METHOD when the Resume button is pressed?

Tags: java, http, wildfly

**Prerequisite:**
My website has pages for downloading files and it requests using POST METHOD.  This can not be changed to GET METHOD as the requirement can not be met.  Also, I can not change client settings, so I need to change server-side processing.  Furthermore, There are no regularity in the URL of the target pages.

**Question:**
When resume button is pressed after downloading fails in Internet Explorer It is requested using GET METHOD, and the data necessary for download processing can not be found.

Can I do one of the following to get around this?

1. Send the same data using POST METHOD when the resume button is pressed.
2. Do not display the resume button.
3. When the user clicks the resume button, it fails without connecting to the server.
4. The server detects that the resume button has been pressed. Then I can generate any error, such as a 404 error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For 1-3: No, that is caused by the inner workings of Internet Explorer, and your website cannot manage that. For 4: Yes, of course, you can. Configure your webserver trigger for any GET request and show a message, however, I am unsure if internet explorer will display the message or simply fail again. Edit, nevermind just saw your edit, that makes things harder.

Comment: sorifiend, thank you for your comment.  
And I'm sorry I couldn't explain the details.  
I can achieve 4 if I manage and determine that the request is a GET METHOD and a download request.  
However, the website I'm involved with are huge, and some pages use GET METHOD.  
Therefore, managing all pages is not realistic.  
Is there a direct way to know if the resume button has been pressed?  
I understand that it is probably difficult.

Comment: If you don't know which URL is a download and which URL a regular page, then no, there is no quick and easy way that I can think of. While not ideal you could add a disclaimer before each download button that says something like "Do not close the page until the download is complete", that way if it fails then the user can just click your download button again. Another more experienced user may be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: I have the same view as you.
Thanks to your comment I became a little more confident.
I'll wait a little while for other users' comments.